# range.getClientRects() is returning 0 rectangle when used with textarea in HTML

Tags: javascript, jquery

I need position of rectangle for each word in textarea using the range API.
When I have "Hello World" in text area I need dimension of rectangle around Hello World by setting the range for Hello World and calling getClientRects() method on range object.

When I tried to get the client rectangle object for text node inside div,span, p etc, it is working fine but for textarea it is returning empty DomRect object

HTML:

`<textarea id="text" style="height=50px;width=50px">Hello World</textarea>`

JAVASCRIPT:

```
var mainDiv = document.getElementById("text");
let chelidnodes  = Array.from(mainDiv.childNodes).filter(n => n.nodeType === n.TEXT_NODE)

var startNode = chelidnodes[0];
var range = document.createRange();
range.setStart(startNode, 0);
range.setEnd(startNode, 11); 
rects = range.getClientRects();
```

When I replace textarea in HTML with div range.getClientRects() will return DomRect Object but with text area it is returning empty DomRect Object.

Answer (score 1):

https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=389054
Issue 389054: Range.getClientRects() returns empty rectangle list for valid text node offset

Answer (score 0):

TextArea does not have child nodes, so `chelidnodes` will be always empty and therefore `range.getClientRects()` too.